# AutoZoom on search by keywords in GMap.NET WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, gmap.net

Is it possible in GMap.NET WPF control to adjust map zoom dependent on the location that I am positioning using ´setPositionByKeyword()´?

For now on, the zoom stays always on its initial (or zoomed by scroll) level. I would like to it to be dependent on what do I search for. For example when I am searching a country i want zoom to be smaller, and when I am searching a town, i want it to be bigger, to properly show desired location.

Answer (score 1):

The [`SetPositionByKeywords` returns a point](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/96bcb11a201ec38ef3bf6ca37d9a36f1edfea738/GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMapControl.cs#L1983), so only from this it's not possible to adapt the zoom to reflect the area occupied by what you've searched.

Now if this is not an open search and you're using predefined keywords, then you could map an area to each keyword, which spans the area that should be visible. Then you can use the [`SetZoomToFitRect` method](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/96bcb11a201ec38ef3bf6ca37d9a36f1edfea738/GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMapControl.cs#L1123) to adjust the zoom accordingly.

If this is intended to be an open search (e.g. an search text field) then it's not possible afaik.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But maybe it is possible to request any map provider (like GoogleMap) what should be the zoom (or rect) for desired place?

Comment: Could be possible, do you have knowledge about providers with this ability?
 You'd still also need to adapt that within the gmap.net code, which is perfectly possible though.

Comment: As I see the method that you've mentioned sets `gp = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap as GeocodingProvider;` So as I understand every map uses OpenStreetMap to find locations. Maybe there is a possibility to get it from there.

Comment: Could be, you need to give it a try, can you fork the project and give it a try?

Comment: I'm afraid that for now on I have no time for that :)